# Выполнять одинаковый код PHP во всех файлах

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот код выполнялся во всех файлах:

```
<?php
    echo '<script src='script.js'></script>';
?>
```

То есть открываю любую страницу на локальном сайте и в начале всегда `<script src='script.js'></script>`.
И при этом чтобы не писать это в каждом файле.
(Использую Open Server)

Comment: Обычно такое помещают перед `</body>`, в худшем сценарии развития событий в `<head>`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, у меня и так работать будет. Главное сделать хоть как есть.

Comment: Да как бы я не о том, что будет ли работать JS. Вы `<!doctype html>` тоже через `echo` выводите?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, и без него работает.

Comment: "в каждом файле" - на каждую страницу сайта свой файл? или все запросы идут в один файл?

Comment: @Skywave, в один

Comment: Тогда для того, чтобы оно просто заработало, достаточно в этом одном файле прописать то что у вас в вопросе.

Comment: @Skywave, мне надо чтобы ничего нигде не писать и чтобы PHP выполнялся на всех страницах

Answer (score 2):

Крайне примитивный пример.
Представьте сайт как три отдельных файла. 
**header** - в него подключаются стили, js, и содержит html код шапки (т.к. она везде одинаковая)
**content** - содержит только контент для вывода
**footer** - (скрипты тоже могут быть подключены тут) и содержит html код футера (т.к. он тоже одинаковый на всех страницах)

И например в index.php вы инклюдите хедер, контент и футер.

И когда вам в дальнейшем нужно что-то добавить на все страницы (как ваша js либа), ее просто подключаете в хедере.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос

> Выполнять одинаковый код PHP во всех файлах

Вставить в том месте, где у вас находится хедер

Comment: Идея хорошая, но лучше чтобы вообще ничего не писать. Открываешь пустую страницу, но там появляется скрипт. Вот так надо.